# Network Manager Issues after upgrading to 12.10

Tags: upgrade, 12.10, network-manager, resolv.conf

I Have upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10 and upgrade went smoothly, but after the restart I was not able to access the Internet and unable to ping any Domain like google.com, though i was able to access my wireless router.

After investigating i found out that /etc/resolv.conf contains Loopback address(127.0.0.1) I updated this file with google public DNS address (8.8.8.8) and tried to restart Network Manager and then my system got struck eventually I have to reboot it.After Rebooting I was able to access internet , but problem doesn't get over yet now when ever I switch the network DNS Network doesn't get change with network( i am on DHCP) , which i need to change manually every time.

I understand that the loop back address was correct /etc/resolv.conf as Network manger should handle the DNS Server but unfortunately it didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 1):

the answer above is cool but all the other devices on my network no longer have dns after my 12.10 connects to the 5g ie 801.11n part of the router.  i have to reset the router for all of the devices to get dns again.  so 12.10 will make windows 8 users flock to ubuntu? with this issue, it should work, not ask people to do several workaround or only connect to 802.11g side of router only.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the symbolic link /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf is missing on your system. To restore it, do the following in a terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install resolvconf
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```